React: Function instered within onClick vs function in component's body
Let's say I have two sample components written in React with logging functions. Where is better performance?
Component 1:
const Component = () => { 
 function test() { console.log('test'); } 
 return (<div onClick={test}>Test</div>) 
}

Component 2:
const Component = () => {
 return (<div onClick={() => console.log('test')}>Test</div>)
}

My questions:

Which component performs better and why?
Is the test function reference somewhere stored and optimized by React or it's just destroyed so there is no better performing Component in this case?

Tried to ask Microsoft Copilot and I have checked multiple forums about that, couldn't find the solution.

They're essentially the same, React doesn't optimise the named function vs the anonymous one.

Related: Anonymous function vs named function on event handlers

@NickParsons so, if I write in component above return (or render): const result = condition ? 1 : 2; there is no difference between this example and this one where I write the condition inside return (render)? Like: return ({condition ? 1 :2 })?

a. Rendering logic can write in the body of a component.
b. Rendering logic can write inside the JSX of a component as well.
Now answering the question - Is there any performance difference between these two codes ?
The answer is no, no performance difference in simply changing the position of the codes. The reasoning is there is nothing automatically memoized based on the position of the codes. Please look at the following sample codes.
The codes {result} and {true ? 'true' : 'false'} in the two components below are essentially the same - two JavaScript expressions. As you know, an expression always results a value when it is evaluated. And please note that it is evaluated every time the return statement is executed. It means for every render of the App component, the two JavaScript expressions in the two components are always evaluated and the value is derived. This value becomes the part of the JSX and it returned from the two components. For more about expressions, please see the answer here Expressions.
App.js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentOne />
      <ComponentTwo />
    </>
  );
}

function ComponentOne() {
  let result;
  if (true) {
    result = 'true';
  } else {
    result = 'false';
  }
  return <div>The result is : {result}</div>;
}

function ComponentTwo() {
  return <div>The result is : {true ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>;
}

The same explanation is applicable to the below two components as well. As we can see the difference over here is in the expressions only. As you know, functions are also expressions since it returns a value when it is evaluated or invoked. By the way functions do not have explicit return values will return undefined as its implicit values. The functions in this case do the same.
App.js

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ComponentOne />
      <ComponentTwo />
    </>
  );
}

function ComponentOne() {
  function test() {
    console.log('test');
  }
  return <div onClick={test}>ComponentOne</div>;
}

function ComponentTwo() {
  return <div onClick={() => console.log('test')}>ComponentTwo</div>;
}

Pointers
Performance optimisation is basically achieved by following a few principles detailed here Should you add useMemo everywhere?
For further steps on this, please look into useMemo here, useMemo
